# Subscribe to SignalR websocket method

Tags: php, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

I am working on my PHP signalr websocket client here https://github.com/marcelmolenaar/php-signalr-client (which i forked from https://github.com/alexwight/php-signalr-client ).

I am trying to get live data from the BitTrex websocket. It seems that my client can connect but i wonder how to subscribe to methods on their server because the library does not offer a convenient method for it as far as i can see (i searched for a subscribe method).

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Marcel Molenaar

Answer (score 1):

There is no official Bittrex Websocket docs, as far as I know.

However, by examining messages on their site https://bittrex.com/home/markets and inspecting this node library https://github.com/dparlevliet/node.bittrex.api I concluded that messages should be of format: `{"H":hubname,"M": methodName, "A": args, "I": messageId}`.

Using this format I have forked from https://github.com/alexwight/php-signalr-client, added subscribe method and tested it. Works well so far. 
Here is the fork https://github.com/pavlefuture/php-signalr-client.